# How can I write all changes in the database once the user confirms it?

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I made a menu where the user can access multiple buttons to **rotate** and **change the status** of a document. Every time the user selects a button the changes will be written into the **realm database**.

---

```
//changes the status of the dc
case "changeStatus" :
            if let marker = documentationMarkers.first(where: {$0.documentationId == doc.id}) {
                let nav = UINavigationController()
                let ctrl = StatusPickerViewController()
                ctrl.delegate = self
                nav.pushViewController(ctrl, animated: true)
                nav.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
                self.present(nav, animated: true)
                nav.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .any
                nav.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = marker
                nav.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = marker.bounds
            }

//rotates the document
case "rotateMarker" :
            if let marker = documentationMarkers.first(where: {$0.documentationId == doc.id}) {
                marker.rotate()
                let documentation = documentations.first(where: {$0.id == marker.documentationId})

                var rotation = documentation?.rotation.value ?? 0

                rotation = (rotation + 15) % 360

                _ = self.updateRotation(documentation: documentation!, rotationAngle: rotation)
            }
```

**updateRotation** method is in a storage extension and writes the changes into the db:

```
func updateRotation(documentation: Documentation, rotationAngle: Int) throws {
        if let realm = try? Realm() {
            try realm.write {
                documentation.updated = Date()
                documentation.rotation.value = rotationAngle
            }

            return
        }

        throw MobiplanError.invalidStateError(message: "Opening the database failed")
    }
```

My **confirm button** is empty at the moment cause I did not know how to implement it so that the changes will be committed into the database when its pressed and not every time another button is selected.

So f.e. when you press the **rotate button** 100 times, it changes the database 100 times. It should only change it once when you press confirm.

I thought of a **struct** with nullable types with the **rotation** and **status**

```
struct DocumentationChanges {
    var statusId: String
    var rotation: Int
}
```

Comment: Uh... Maybe move the write to Realm code to the confirm button? I'm not sure I fully understand your question.

Comment: you need to keep track of all rotations on confirm action or just final rotation made before pressing confirm?? so i can help you out

Comment: @MuhammadAfzal yeah of all rotations made. You can press the rotation button 100x times and it changes the database 100x. But it should only change it once when you press confirm

Comment: then your struct is fine use rotation as array instead of single Int and keep writing changes to DocumentationChanges object because their will be single status and multiple rotations let me know if you need code.

Comment: You're not making sense. You're stating that the database should change every time the user rotates, but also the database should change only once you press confirm. You might want to store all the performed rotations in an array and then write all of them at once in the database or...?

Comment: @Roberto yeah, I want to apply the change the database once the user confirms it and not every time a button is selected. When I store them in an array the rotations won´t be applied on my view or am I wrong?

Comment: @MuhammadAfzal I would appreciate it. Can´t figure it out at the moment.

Comment: can you share source code at mobileappscraze@gmail.com?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your current code doesn't write anything to your Realm database, nor your struct has any nullable type.

In order to implement what you want, you could create a `DocumentationChanges` array, and everytime your user press the rotation button, save the new rotation in the array.

When the user clicks the confirm button, save the array in your Realm database.

Something like this to save your rotations:

```swift
var rotationStory = [DocumentationChanges]()
func updateRotation(documentation: Documentation, rotationAngle: Int) {
    let documentationChange = DocumentationChanges(statusId, rotationAngle)
    rotationStory.append(documentationChange)
}
```

And then this to store all the performed rotations in the database, once the confirm button is clicked:

```swift
func storeToRealm() {
    do {
        if let database = try? Realm()
        try database.write {
           database.add(rotationStory)
        }
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}
```

Comment: **_ = self.updateRotation(documentation: documentation!, rotationAngle: rotation)** calls the above func in my code and writes the changes into the database ( I thought it does...)